# Anychart Scatter Bubble Chart zoom

Tags: zooming, scatter-plot, bubble-chart, anychart

I am using the `Scatter Plot` with `bubble()` mode. I have a lot of points to display and a lot of them are on top of each other or really close and it is difficult to differentiate. So I have tried to use `anychart.ui.zoom().render(scatterChart)` but it throws the error `Uncaught TypeError: a.insertBefore is not a function`. Is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `anychart.ui.zoom().render(scatterChart)` is acceptable only for Maps. For Scatter chart you can use other approaches. 
You can add x- and y-scrollers, check the sample below

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

  var stage = anychart.graphics.create('container');

  // create data
  var data = [
    {x: 0.6, value: 22},
    {x: 1.7, value: 55},
    {x: 2.3, value: 50},
    {x: 3.5, value: 80},
    {x: 3.9, value: 74},
    {x: 4, value: 68},
    {x: 4, value: 76},
    {x: 4.1, value: 84},
    {x: 4.7, value: 93}
  ];

  // create a chart
  var chart = anychart.scatter();
  // create a marker series and set the data
  var series = chart.marker(data);
  // enable major grids
  chart.xGrid(true);
  chart.yGrid(true);
  // enable minor grids 
  chart.xMinorGrid(true);
  chart.yMinorGrid(true);
  chart.margin({left: 10, bottom: 10});
  chart.xAxis().labels().format('{%value}{decimalsCount:2}');
  chart.yAxis().labels().format('{%value}{decimalsCount:1}');
  // set the container id
  chart.container(stage).draw();

  var bounds = chart.getPixelBounds();

  //create x-scroller
  var xScroller = anychart.standalones.scroller();
  xScroller.parentBounds(60, bounds.height-60, bounds.width-80, 50);
  xScroller.container(stage).draw();

  //create y-scroller
  var yScroller = anychart.standalones.scroller();
  yScroller.orientation('left');
  yScroller.parentBounds(5, 10, 0, bounds.height-60);
  yScroller.container(stage).draw();

  //place scrollers on window resize
  window.onresize = function(event) {
    var bounds = chart.getPixelBounds();
    xScroller.parentBounds(60, bounds.height-60, bounds.width-80, 50);
    yScroller.parentBounds(5, 10, 0, bounds.height-60);
  };

  //get info about scales
  var xScale = chart.xScale();
  var yScale = chart.yScale();

  var minX = xScale.minimum();
  var maxX = xScale.maximum();
  var minY = yScale.minimum();
  var maxY = yScale.maximum();

  //scroller listeners and handlers
  xScroller.listen('scrollerchange', function(e) {
    xScale.minimum(e.startRatio * maxX + minX);
    xScale.maximum(e.endRatio * maxX);
  });

  yScroller.listen('scrollerchange', function(e) {
    yScale.minimum((1 - e.endRatio) * maxY + minY);
    yScale.maximum((1 - e.startRatio) * maxY);
  });
});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.3.0/js/anychart-base.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.3.0/js/anychart-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.3.0/js/anychart-exports.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.3.0/css/anychart-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Or you can zoom to the required range using 'Start selection marquee' from the context menu (right-click)

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
  
  var button = document.getElementById('button');

  var stage = anychart.graphics.create('container');

  // create data
  var data = [
    {x: 0.6, value: 22},
    {x: 1.7, value: 55},
    {x: 2.3, value: 50},
    {x: 3.5, value: 80},
    {x: 3.9, value: 74},
    {x: 4, value: 68},
    {x: 4, value: 76},
    {x: 4.1, value: 84},
    {x: 4.7, value: 93}
  ];

  // create a chart
  var chart = anychart.scatter();
  // create a marker series and set the data
  var series = chart.marker(data);
  // enable major grids
  chart.xGrid(true);
  chart.yGrid(true);
  // enable minor grids 
  chart.xMinorGrid(true);
  chart.yMinorGrid(true);
  chart.margin({left: 10, bottom: 10});
  chart.xAxis().labels().format('{%value}{decimalsCount:2}');
  chart.yAxis().labels().format('{%value}{decimalsCount:1}');
  // set the container id
  chart.container(stage).draw();

  //get info about scales
  var xScale = chart.xScale();
  var yScale = chart.yScale();

  var minX = xScale.minimum();
  var maxX = xScale.maximum();
  var minY = yScale.minimum();
  var maxY = yScale.maximum();

  //button listener
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
   xScale.minimum(minX);
    xScale.maximum(maxX);
    yScale.minimum(minY);
    yScale.maximum(maxY);
  });

  //chart listeners and handlers
  var xAxisBounds = chart.xAxis().getPixelBounds();
  var yAxisBounds = chart.yAxis().getPixelBounds();

  chart.listen('selectMarqueeFinish', function(e) {
    var normalizedX = (e.clientX >= e.startX) ? e.startX : e.clientX;
    var normalizedY = (e.clientY >= e.startY) ? e.startY : e.clientY;
    var startXRatio = (normalizedX - xAxisBounds.left) / xAxisBounds.width;
    var endXRatio = (normalizedX - xAxisBounds.left + e.width) / xAxisBounds.width;
    var startYRatio = (normalizedY - yAxisBounds.top) / yAxisBounds.height;
    var endYRatio = (normalizedY - yAxisBounds.top + e.height) / yAxisBounds.height;

    xScale.minimum(xScale.inverseTransform(startXRatio));
    xScale.maximum(xScale.inverseTransform(endXRatio));
    yScale.minimum(yScale.inverseTransform(1 - endYRatio));
    yScale.maximum(yScale.inverseTransform(1 - startYRatio));
  });
});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.2.1/js/anychart-base.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.2.1/js/anychart-exports.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.2.1/js/anychart-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.2.1/css/anychart-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button id="button">Zoom out</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it answers the problem. If I have `title` on the axis, how to position the scrollers nicely between the chart and the title?

Comment: For this purpose, all you need is to increase top padding of the axis title and place the scroller between the axis and its title. For details, check the following sample (lines 31 and 40) - https://playground.anychart.com/PxKRJI3I